# Отобразить по центру большую блочную форму

Tags: html, css

Есть `pushup` окно (большая блочная форма), у нее `position:absolute` и ширина `900px`. Проблема в том что не получается отцентрировать её по центру экрана. На маленьких экранах можно делать оступ по центру через %, но на больших экранах форма уезжает в сторону. Как её выравнять на всех экранах?

Comment: Что служит для неё containing block'ом и какой у него position?

Comment: Контейнером служит размер экрана, position:absolute.

Comment: Центровать и по горизонтали, и по вертикали?

Ширина всегда 900. А высота? Переменная?

Comment: Нет, беда в том что блок берет расстояние от границ экрана. То есть если экран шириной в 1280 px, а мой блок 900px, то отступы слева и справа должны быть одинаковыми по 190px.

Проблема в том что если увеличивать диогональ то задавать расстояние по бокам, что бы форма оставалась в центре, - не получается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот вариант для ситуации, когда ширина блока постоянна: http://jsfiddle.net/b5MtS/1/

Все просто:

```
figure {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 900px;
    margin-left: -450px;
}
```

А вот [универсальный вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/n6mPV/) ([UPD](http://jsfiddle.net/n6mPV/3/)).

Смысл его в том, что контейнером служит таблица (на самом деле, другой элемент, но с табличным представлением), которая и растянута на всю ширину `body`. А таблица содержит одну-единственную ячейку, которая выравнивает дочерний элемент по центру:

```
.pushup-container-inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Теперь все, что будет внутри, будет размещено по центру.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я помню это делалось при помощи установки окна в центр и

```
margin: -50%
```

Однако я не сильно понимаю почему не использовать jQuery?

Comment: Можно посмотреть эту jquery функцию?

Comment: Потому что действительно незачем сюда лепить жиквери, если можно все сделать стилями

Comment: HappyCougar, посмотрите модальное окно на jQuery. Я точно не помню как она называется, думаю что это будет много лучше того что вы пытаетесь нагородить, если я правильно понял, что вы хотите сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант.

```
#overlay {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
background: #3d3d3d;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1000;
}

#container {
width: 500px;
height: 350px;
background: #FFF;
margin: 5% auto;
}

<div id="overlay">
    <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```